# Driving a Windows GUI program from a script

Tags: python, winapi, user-interface, automation, gui-testing

I have to use a Windows simulation package to perform a repetitive task with slightly different options each time.

Since I hate repetitive clicking, on grounds of both laziness and the amount of errors that a human introduces, I would like to drive this program automatically. The program in question doesn't support scripting, there is no API, no COM, nada, nyet, nravin. As far as I can tell, the only way to drive this program automatically is to imitate a human (i.e. keyboard and mouse macros.)

I am aware of AutoHotKey but I don't think it does what I want. (Or it might do what I want, but its scripting language is horrible.)

The requirements are:

- Must allow time delays between actions, or event detection to trigger actions.

  The simulations can take up to ten minutes to run, so the GUI driver would have to wait until the simulation finishes before starting a new one.

  One way to do this would be to just wait ten minutes and hope that the simulation has finished. An alternative way is to make it event-driven, i.e. watch for the "Simulation running..." dialog to disappear and be replaced by a "Simulation complete" dialog.
- Must allow composition of complex keyboard input.

  Some of the keyboard input required is different for each simulation run. For example the simulation description might take the format `[Project name][Scenario name][Option 1][Option 2]...` and this would have to be entered for each simulation.

  I am aware that AutoHotKey allows a basic level of input customisation, but my casual reading of the documentation makes the scripting language look like some kind of eldritch horror.
- This is for work, so any solution must be free for commercial use.

I will accept any solution that fits the criteria above, but I have a **strong** preference for something I can drive from Python. However I would also accept automated GUI-testing tools that I could customise to do what I want - possibly a Win32 GUI equivalent of [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for browsers? - keyboard macro recorders that will generate custom output, or anything else that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give Autohotkey another look, from you requirements it seems fit for the job.

Alternatively check UI Automation from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx and also white: http://white.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 11):

> Sikuli is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user
>   interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots). Sikuli includes Sikuli
>   Script, a visual scripting API for Jython, and Sikuli IDE, an
>   integrated development environment for writing visual scripts with
>   screenshots easily. Sikuli Script automates anything you see on the
>   screen without internal API's support. You can programmatically
>   control a web page, a Windows/Linux/Mac OS X desktop application, or
>   even an iphone or android application running in a simulator or via
>   VNC.

Look at [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/), it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) - it is written in Python. It can be used either as a standalone tool or as a Python library in your own scripts:

```
from automa.api import *
```

It allows automation of any Windows application through commands like click, press, write, etc.

Some examples of the automation scripts can be found at http://www.getautoma.com/blog/category/ui-automation-examples

*Disclaimer*: I'm one of Automa's developers.

Comment: Please note that this is a python library that costs money

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm one of Automa's developers.

Please note that this is a python library that costs money 

No thanks

Answer (score 6):

Look at this
https://pywinauto.github.io/

You can use python script itself to control your windows application.

Advantage is:

- no need to learn new language/syntax
- integrates easily with other existing script

Comment: The correct link is now: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PyAutoGUI library](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) for Python which works on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

> Must allow time delays between actions.

Example to type with quarter-second pause in between each key:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!', interval=0.25)
```

Here is the example to set up a 2.5-second pause after each PyAutoGUI call:

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 2.5
```

> Must allow composition of complex keyboard input.

Checkout [keyboard control functions](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) where you can use `pyautogui.typewrite` to type something out. You can pass variables to allow a complex keyboard input.

> Event detection to trigger actions.

You can use [locate functions](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) to visually find something on the screen and make the condition based on that within a simple loop.

> Solution must be free for commercial use.

It is licensed under the BSD which allows commercial use.

---

See also:

- [Which is the easiest way to simulate keyboard and mouse on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2791839/55075)
- [Python GUI automation library for simulating user interaction in apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42664/3474).

Comment: I can't edit this answer ("suggested edit queue is full"), but the first link is now broken.  Corrected link is: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/windows.html) is not using Python but otherwise fits the bill. It is like Selenium but for Win32 **and** web.

RIATest uses Windows UI Automation API and can drive any Windows application that exposes its GUI to UI Automation properly (that includes all native and .NET apps).

*Disclaimer: I work for Cogitek, the RIATest company.*