# How to automate a GUI application's operation using python in GNU/Linux?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, automation

How to automate gthumb - 'enhance colours' option?

gThumb is a nice image management software available for GNU/Linux.

When we see an image, we can enhance the colours easily, in gthumb.

But, we have to click a image, then have to click the button for
enhancing the colours.

Is there any way to automate the process for clicking all the images
in the gthumb collection and apply 'enhance colours' option for all
the images?

http://www.screenr.com/1ZB8

Here is a little screencast on how I have to click each image and enhance it.

Looking for automating all this activities.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698512/driving-a-windows-gui-program-from-a-script). Check out Sikuli for your GUI-program automation needs - I think it runs on Linux, it's Python-scriptable, and it's just damned **cool**.

Alternately, if your ["enhance colours" operation could be done using ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/enhance.php), you could do this in batch mode using ImageMagick's `convert` command at the command line. Provided ImageMagick supports the kind of enhancement you want, this will be much faster and more reliable than automating a GUI.

Comment: ImageMagick is a very nice option, as it'll be a lot easier than scripting a GUI app.

Answer (score 1):

PyAutoGUI (installable through pip) can automate mouse/keyboard and works on Mac/Windows/Linux.

It also has some basic screenshot image recognition capabilities like Sikuli has. You can just supply a png of something you want to click on instead of coordinates.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI

It's fairly well documented as well: http://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/