# Can python imitate the mouse and follow orders?

Tags: python, process

There a manual work process that I'd like to automate. In essence the process is: 1. Open program.exe
2. Select title menu, select 2nd option
3. Enter date range
4. Hit submit
5. Repeat steps 2-4 with varied date ranges.

Is python able to identified fields within a program and imitate mouse click/key strokes?

Comment: I'm sure you could make it with python but you might want to look at [autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/)

Comment: ie. [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python: Controlling the Keyboard and Mouse with GUI Automation](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/) but maybe there are better method.

Comment: Thank Autohotkey is the key to this!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the easiest way to simulate keyboard and mouse on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python)