# SendKeys python UAC

Tags: python

everyone. 
As part of the automation process I use SendKeys in PYTHON
I am trying to open CMD as Administrator and as soon the UAC PROMPT opens, send it enter
But it does not work. there is a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the easiest way to simulate keyboard and mouse on Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python)

Comment: So you want to bypass the Windows security system? I'd be really surprised if you could do it so easily.