# Mouse click an app with python

Tags: python, mouseevent, pywinauto

so my problem is -

I made a simple app in python which checks if a program runs, if not it runs the program and perform a couple of mouse clicks on that program.

For some reason, I can't mouse click the program, Altho if I set it to just do some mouse click on the desktop for example it works great...
Any chance that the program blocks my automated clicks? shouldn't it stimulate a normal mouse click as I click my self?

attaching a code just so will see how I make the mouse click -

```
        app.update()
        app.focus_force()
        pywinauto.mouse.click(button='left', coords=(1096, 728))
```

btw, Iv'e also tried to make the clicks with simple ctypes which didn't help.

thanks for reading.

Comment: Is that target program publicly available? Did you ever try to use Inspect.exe?

Comment: The [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) may help you to solve this challenge step by step. You may use not only clicks but other more complicated functions that don't do realistic click like a real user.

Comment: Thanks, problem was that I didn't ran the script with elevated privileges... probably its needed cuz I run the process with elevated priviliges aswell

Comment: Ah, yes. This is pretty common problem. I'm planning to add some warning if there are no enough privileges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the easiest way to simulate keyboard and mouse on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python)

Answer (score 1):

Well, eventually all I needed was to make sure I run the script with elevated privileges.

when doing so everything works fine.

How you do that -

Run cmd as adminstrator -> navigate to your script folder - > python script.py