# Simulate key press on Windows

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python and this is my first script:

```
import os, time

class Key(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.key = 'Hello World! '
        time.sleep(3) 
        for x in range(10):
            self.simulate()

    def simulate(self):
        cmd = "osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" + self.key + "\"'"
        os.system(cmd)

key = Key()
key
```

It will simply type `Hello World!` 10 times after 3 seconds.

This works great but my method `simulate(self)` only works on OS X. How can I make it work on Windows as well?

Comment: the problem is mostly that `osascript` isn't a windows function.
The solution is easy to find if you search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python#2791979

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd exactly, that's the point! But is there an alternative function for Windows?

Comment: in the question I have linked you can see the easiest option for windows. as far as I know it isn't possible to use a cmd command for that.

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd thank you for this info. I will try that.