# How to minimize opened application with subprocess.call()

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess, mp3

I want to play the .mp3 sound from my application without player popping-up over all the windows. Is the the way to minimize the player direct upon opening?

```
subprocess.call('start english.mp3', shell=True)
```

Python 3.3, Windows 8.1

I appreciate any help and advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791489/how-do-i-take-out-the-focus-or-minimize-a-window-with-python#2791812).

I think there'll be a problem with that approach, though: you'll still have the window open on the few milliseconds it will take you to minimize it, so it can annoy the user.

Another option is actually telling the player to not create the window by default. 
VLC, for example, supports the `--qt-start-minimized` argument:

```
subprocess.call(['vlc', '--qt-start-minimized', 'english.mp3'])
```

Don't forget to use absolute paths (to the player and file) if necessary

Comment: Thank you, it works. Probably it is easier to include vlc into our software distribution than trying to handle any unknown player user may have as default.